# Determining which files of a rather complicated PHP script are generating the output?

Tags: php, debugging

I've purchased an open-source website, and need to do some modifications which are mainly related to "appearance".

Problem is I can't discover which files generate the output, figured they must be in a "layouts" folder or something, and didn't find anything.

Is there a way in PHP to help me do this and maybe be useful in debugging the website later on?

Thanks.

Comment: Open the project in your favorite editor -> find a somewhat unique thing on the page -> find through files

Comment: add loggers to your code.. that might help u a lot

Comment: Also, view the source and see if there is a theme/layout dir that has images, stylesheets, etc.

Comment: Already tried looking for unique text in page source, that didn't work.

I didn't write the code, I purchased it, so i guess adding loggers won't be possible?

Comment: var_dump(debug_backtrace());
was useless as well.